# Yii: Styling for site

Tags: css, yii

I am almost completely ready with my Yii Website. Now I would like to completely change the default styling of the site.
Are there any templates and what is the best way to begin the styling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some Free yii themes , try this

[Yii themes](http://yii.themefactory.net/theme-browser)

Here some responsive theme,

[Yii Booster](http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/)

[Yii strap](http://www.getyiistrap.com/)

[Yii Twitter bootstrap](http://www.cniska.net/yii-bootstrap/)

and Yii theming guide

[Yii theming Guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.theming)

Answer (score 2):

Just complementing what @ramamoorthy_villi said, you can browse some HTML themes on

http://themeforest.net/

they have a huge archive, and some of them are really cheap. If you need some more professional, you can find a lot of material in there.